# Why doesn't inotifywait notice the change in /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness (Linux)

Tags: linux, bash, inotify, backlight

My laptop has a 4K OLED screen, so it has no backlight to change the brightness of the screen. To control the brightness, you need to use xrandr with the --brightness parameter. I have successfully done this in the i3 window manager before but I would now like to to something similar in Budgie.

Budgie will detect the brightness keystrokes and will change the /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness file contents to a value that would normally update the backlight setting.

I would like to monitor this file for changes and when it changes, just call xrandr with the correct value... I found out that you can watch file changes with inotifywait but for some reason, it doesn't work for me.

```
$ cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
21750
# Now pressing the brightness up key on the keyboard
$ cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
28000
$ inotifywait /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
Setting up watches.
Watches established.
# Now pressing the brightness up key on the keyboard....... nothing happens.
# Same when I add the -e close_write parameter.
```

Anyone knows why this happens?

I could of course just check the file's contents every second but I don't like that kind of solution.

FYI: Arch Linux, up to date

Edit: I just noticed that it DOES notice changes in /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness which solves my problem, but the question is still valid.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/398204/inotifywait-not-alterting-when-device-created for some suggestions

Comment: Doesn't really help: the file system is ext4 in both cases and someone else seems to have been able to do it on his computer (just found https://github.com/lawleagle/oled-linux doing exactly what I am doing), so this problem must be on a different level. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @scippie /sys is a psuedo-filesystem for interacting with the kernel. it's not ext4

Comment: Right, that makes sense. But that even gives me more question marks why it works for someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inotify works at the VFS level (filesystem level, so to speak). If the *file* is written into, inotify will be notified of it. However, since sysfs (and procfs, and all other virtual filesystems) have contents that are possibly updated dynamically & asynchronously *not via the filesystem*, using inotify may not yield the expected results.

In your case - the value of `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` may be updated someway else, not via the filesystem, while `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness` does get updated through the filesystem. That depends on the controlling software. This may be the cause for your observation.

For the record - I have tested it on my laptop: with `inotifywatch /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` running in the background, I get notified on:

- `cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` - `close_nowrite`.
- `echo 50000 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` - changes the brightness and I get `close_write`.
- Changing the brightness via the keyboard shortcut - for each increase/decrease I get 1 `close_write` event (running `GNOME Shell 3.36.4`)

Comment: Thanks. I think it is safe to say that it's not safe to depend on it :-)